# How to receive Messages from RabbitMQ as a background job using Bunny gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background, rabbitmq

I'm using RabbitMQ and the following task to receive the  messages from Consumer.

**lib/task/rabbitmq.rake**

```
  require "rubygems"
  require 'bunny'
  connection = Bunny.new(user: "sample_user", password: "*****", host: '**')
  connection.start
  channel = connection.create_channel
  queue = channel.queue('queue', :durable => true)
  begin
    puts ' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C'
    queue.subscribe(block: true) do |_delivery_info, _properties, body|
      MyModel.my_function(body)
    end
  rescue Interrupt => _
    puts ' [*] Error fetching for messages. To exit press CTRL+C'
    connection.close
    exit(0)
  end
```

I need to process this task as a background job and i want to re-start whenever i deploy my application.

I used to start the task using the below command to work in background and it's working fine but how do i restart the job without killing the PID manually?

**bundle exec rake rabbitmq:event jobs:work QUEUE="rabbitmq" --trace > log/rabbitmq.log 2>&1 &**

Also i want to use this as a service in capistrano to start/restart the service while deploy.